# Почему при назаначении атрибута по умолчания 0 выходит такая ошибка: IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
class Restaurant():

    def __init__(self, restaurant_name, cuisine_type):
        self.restaurant_name=restaurant_name
        self.cuisine_type=cuisine_type
        self.served = 0 #в чем ошибка?

    def describe_restaurant(self):
        print(f"{self.restaurant_name} ({self.cuisine_type}) is wonderful place for visiting")

    def open_restaurant(self):
        print(f"{self.restaurant_name} is open today")

    def number_served(self):
        print(f"The number of people served: {self.served}")

    def update_served(self, update):
        self.served=update

restaurant=Restaurant('Огни Ташкента', 'национальная кухня')
restaurant2=Restaurant('Yapona mama', 'pan asian')
restaurant3=Restaurant('Miliy taomlar', 'National uzbek food')

restaurant.describe_restaurant()
restaurant.open_restaurant()
restaurant.update_served(45)
restaurant.number_served()
```

Comment: Попробуйте скопировать ваш код из вопроса и запустить его еще раз.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level` говорит о проблеме с отступами в коде. Скопируйте код из этого вопроса, он должен сработать. У меня по крайней мере он работает.